# How can i make a python program that downloads memes

Tags: python, video

I'm new to this platform

How can I make a python script that will go to websites (ex. Instagram, reddit, etc) and download memes and put them into a folder.

I searched it up and I could not find any solution to my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is very broad question. What did you try? I recommend to look into and install the necessary libraries: `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` and scrape the website content. From there you can process the raw data further.

You'll need the requests library to send HTTP requests and then you can download the memes or any images, and the `BeautifulSoup` library will help you to parse the HTML and extract the image URLs which you can download.

However, this will not work for instagram, for that you will need to use Selenium.

Here is a most basic code just to give you an idea how to download a single image or meme:

```
import requests

def download_image(url, my_images):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(my_images, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)

image_url = 'https://example.com/some_meme.jpg'
some_var = 'some_meme.jpg'
download_image(image_url, some_var)
```